# Flutter iOS app keeps crashing in Release Mode for Authenticated users

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have been working on a project which is using cloud firestore for storing data. The issue I am having is that my ios app keeps crashing for authenticated users when the application is being downloaded from the app store or testflight. I am attaching the screenshots of errors that I was able to retrieve from Testflight as this app works fine for debug mode.

**From App store crash logs**
[image]

**When opened in the project**
[image]

**Steps to reproduce**

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

- Download the application from here [App Store Link](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/physiosite/id1663719876)
- Register a new account or login using theses credentials (email: test@demo.com, password: 12345678)
- Close the application and remove form recently opened apps from your device
- Open the application again and you will see a white screen and app will crash immediately.

**Expected behavior**

This application should let users to access their data and perform the said tasks.

**Flutter doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-x64, locale
    en-PK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

**Flutter dependencies**

```
Dart SDK 3.0.2
Flutter SDK 3.10.2
fitness 1.1.0+5

dependencies:
- add_2_calendar 2.2.3 [flutter]
- agora_rtc_engine 6.2.0 [flutter flutter_web_plugins json_annotation ffi async meta iris_method_channel]
- animated_widgets 1.1.0 [flutter vector_math]
- audio_waveforms 1.0.4 [flutter]
- calendar_date_picker2 0.5.2 [flutter]
- carousel_slider 4.2.1 [flutter]
- cloud_firestore 4.8.0 [cloud_firestore_platform_interface cloud_firestore_web collection firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- connectivity_plus 4.0.1 [flutter flutter_web_plugins connectivity_plus_platform_interface js meta nm]
- country_state_city_picker 1.0.1 [flutter dropdown_search]
- crypto 3.0.3 [typed_data]
- cupertino_icons 1.0.5
- dotted_line 3.1.0 [flutter]
- duration_picker 1.1.1 [flutter]
- firebase_auth 4.6.2 [firebase_auth_platform_interface firebase_auth_web firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- firebase_core 2.13.1 [firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_core_web flutter meta]
- firebase_messaging 14.6.2 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_messaging_platform_interface firebase_messaging_web flutter meta]
- firebase_storage 11.2.2 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_storage_platform_interface firebase_storage_web flutter]
- fl_chart 0.62.0 [equatable flutter]
- flutter 0.0.0 [characters collection js material_color_utilities meta vector_math sky_engine]
- flutter_date_pickers 0.4.2 [flutter intl flutter_localizations]
- flutter_local_notifications 14.1.1 [clock flutter flutter_local_notifications_linux flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface timezone]
- flutter_svg 2.0.6 [flutter vector_graphics vector_graphics_codec vector_graphics_compiler]
- fluttertoast 8.2.2 [flutter flutter_web_plugins]
- font_awesome_flutter 10.4.0 [flutter]
- geocoding 2.1.0 [flutter geocoding_platform_interface geocoding_android geocoding_ios]
- geolocator 9.0.2 [flutter geolocator_platform_interface geolocator_android geolocator_apple geolocator_web geolocator_windows]
- get 4.6.5 [flutter]
- google_fonts 4.0.4 [flutter http path_provider crypto]
- health 4.6.0 [flutter intl device_info_plus]
- http 0.13.6 [async http_parser meta]
- image_picker 0.8.7+5 [flutter image_picker_android image_picker_for_web image_picker_ios image_picker_platform_interface]
- intl 0.18.0 [clock meta path]
- just_audio 0.9.34 [just_audio_platform_interface just_audio_web audio_session rxdart path path_provider async uuid crypto meta flutter]
- keyboard_actions 4.2.0 [flutter]
- keyboard_dismisser 3.0.0 [flutter]
- music_visualizer 1.0.2 [flutter]
- permission_handler 10.2.0 [flutter meta permission_handler_android permission_handler_apple permission_handler_windows permission_handler_platform_interface]
- pinput 2.2.31 [flutter smart_auth universal_platform]
- pod_player 0.1.0 [flutter lottie video_player http get wakelock universal_html youtube_explode_dart]
- purchases_flutter 4.12.0 [flutter freezed_annotation json_annotation]
- readmore 2.2.0 [flutter]
- shared_preferences 2.1.1 [flutter shared_preferences_android shared_preferences_foundation shared_preferences_linux shared_preferences_platform_interface shared_preferences_web shared_preferences_windows]
- shimmer 3.0.0 [flutter]
- sign_in_with_apple 4.3.0 [flutter meta sign_in_with_apple_platform_interface sign_in_with_apple_web]
- step_progress_indicator 1.0.2 [flutter]
- timeago 3.4.0 [intl]
- url_launcher 6.1.11 [flutter url_launcher_android url_launcher_ios url_launcher_linux url_launcher_macos url_launcher_platform_interface url_launcher_web url_launcher_windows]
- webview_flutter 4.2.1 [flutter webview_flutter_android webview_flutter_platform_interface webview_flutter_wkwebview]
- workmanager 0.5.1 [flutter]

dev dependencies:
- change_app_package_name 1.1.0
- flutter_launcher_icons 0.13.1 [args checked_yaml cli_util image json_annotation path yaml]
- flutter_lints 2.0.1 [lints]
- flutter_test 0.0.0 [flutter test_api path fake_async clock stack_trace vector_math async boolean_selector characters collection js matcher material_color_utilities meta source_span stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph]

transitive dependencies:
- _flutterfire_internals 1.3.2 [collection firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- archive 3.3.7 [crypto path pointycastle]
- args 2.4.1
- async 2.11.0 [collection meta]
- audio_session 0.1.15 [flutter flutter_web_plugins rxdart meta]
- boolean_selector 2.1.1 [source_span string_scanner]
- characters 1.3.0
- charcode 1.3.1
- checked_yaml 2.0.3 [json_annotation source_span yaml]
- cli_util 0.4.0 [meta path]
- clock 1.1.1
- cloud_firestore_platform_interface 5.15.0 [_flutterfire_internals collection firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- cloud_firestore_web 3.6.0 [_flutterfire_internals cloud_firestore_platform_interface collection firebase_core firebase_core_web flutter flutter_web_plugins js]
- collection 1.17.1
- connectivity_plus_platform_interface 1.2.4 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- convert 3.1.1 [typed_data]
- cross_file 0.3.3+4 [js meta]
- csslib 0.17.3 [source_span]
- dbus 0.7.8 [args ffi meta xml]
- device_info_plus 8.2.2 [device_info_plus_platform_interface ffi file flutter flutter_web_plugins meta win32]
- device_info_plus_platform_interface 7.0.0 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- dropdown_search 5.0.6 [flutter]
- equatable 2.0.5 [collection meta]
- fake_async 1.3.1 [clock collection]
- ffi 2.0.2
- file 6.1.4 [meta path]
- firebase_auth_platform_interface 6.15.2 [_flutterfire_internals collection firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_auth_web 5.5.2 [firebase_auth_platform_interface firebase_core firebase_core_web flutter flutter_web_plugins http_parser js meta]
- firebase_core_platform_interface 4.8.0 [collection flutter flutter_test meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_core_web 2.5.0 [firebase_core_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins js meta]
- firebase_messaging_platform_interface 4.5.2 [_flutterfire_internals firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_messaging_web 3.5.2 [_flutterfire_internals firebase_core firebase_core_web firebase_messaging_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins js meta]
- firebase_storage_platform_interface 4.4.2 [collection firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_storage_web 3.6.2 [_flutterfire_internals async firebase_core firebase_core_web firebase_storage_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins http js meta]
- flutter_local_notifications_linux 4.0.0+1 [dbus ffi flutter flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface path xdg_directories]
- flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface 7.0.0+1 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- flutter_localizations 0.0.0 [flutter intl characters clock collection js material_color_utilities meta path vector_math]
- flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 2.0.15 [flutter]
- flutter_web_plugins 0.0.0 [flutter js characters collection material_color_utilities meta vector_math]
- freezed_annotation 2.2.0 [collection json_annotation meta]
- geocoding_android 2.1.0 [flutter geocoding_platform_interface]
- geocoding_ios 2.1.0 [flutter geocoding_platform_interface]
- geocoding_platform_interface 2.0.1 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- geolocator_android 4.1.8 [flutter geolocator_platform_interface]
- geolocator_apple 2.2.5 [flutter geolocator_platform_interface]
- geolocator_platform_interface 4.0.7 [flutter plugin_platform_interface vector_math meta]
- geolocator_web 2.1.6 [flutter flutter_web_plugins geolocator_platform_interface]
- geolocator_windows 0.1.1 [flutter geolocator_platform_interface]
- html 0.15.3 [csslib source_span]
- http_parser 4.0.2 [collection source_span string_scanner typed_data]
- image 4.0.17 [archive meta xml]
- image_picker_android 0.8.6+19 [flutter flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle image_picker_platform_interface]
- image_picker_for_web 2.1.12 [flutter flutter_web_plugins image_picker_platform_interface]
- image_picker_ios 0.8.7+4 [flutter image_picker_platform_interface]
- image_picker_platform_interface 2.6.3 [cross_file flutter http plugin_platform_interface]
- iris_method_channel 1.1.0 [flutter ffi async]
- js 0.6.7 [meta]
- json_annotation 4.8.1 [meta]
- just_audio_platform_interface 4.2.1 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- just_audio_web 0.4.8 [just_audio_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins]
- lints 2.1.1
- lottie 2.4.0 [archive flutter path vector_math]
- matcher 0.12.15 [async meta stack_trace term_glyph test_api]
- material_color_utilities 0.2.0
- meta 1.9.1
- nm 0.5.0 [dbus]
- path 1.8.3
- path_parsing 1.0.1 [vector_math meta]
- path_provider 2.0.15 [flutter path_provider_android path_provider_foundation path_provider_linux path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_windows]
- path_provider_android 2.0.27 [flutter path_provider_platform_interface]
- path_provider_foundation 2.2.3 [flutter path_provider_platform_interface]
- path_provider_linux 2.1.11 [ffi flutter path path_provider_platform_interface xdg_directories]
- path_provider_platform_interface 2.0.6 [flutter platform plugin_platform_interface]
- path_provider_windows 2.1.6 [ffi flutter path path_provider_platform_interface win32]
- permission_handler_android 10.2.1 [flutter permission_handler_platform_interface]
- permission_handler_apple 9.0.8 [flutter permission_handler_platform_interface]
- permission_handler_platform_interface 3.9.0 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- permission_handler_windows 0.1.2 [flutter permission_handler_platform_interface]
- petitparser 5.4.0 [meta]
- platform 3.1.0
- plugin_platform_interface 2.1.4 [meta]
- pointycastle 3.7.3 [collection convert js]
- process 4.2.4 [file path platform]
- rxdart 0.27.7
- shared_preferences_android 2.1.4 [flutter shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_foundation 2.2.2 [flutter shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_linux 2.2.0 [file flutter path path_provider_linux path_provider_platform_interface shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_platform_interface 2.2.0 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_web 2.1.0 [flutter flutter_web_plugins shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_windows 2.2.0 [file flutter path path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_windows shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- sign_in_with_apple_platform_interface 1.0.0 [flutter plugin_platform_interface meta]
- sign_in_with_apple_web 1.0.1 [flutter flutter_web_plugins sign_in_with_apple_platform_interface js]
- sky_engine 0.0.99
- smart_auth 1.0.8 [flutter flutter_web_plugins]
- source_span 1.9.1 [collection path term_glyph]
- stack_trace 1.11.0 [path]
- stream_channel 2.1.1 [async]
- string_scanner 1.2.0 [source_span]
- term_glyph 1.2.1
- test_api 0.5.1 [async boolean_selector collection meta source_span stack_trace stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph matcher]
- timezone 0.9.2 [path]
- typed_data 1.3.2 [collection]
- universal_html 2.2.3 [async csslib charcode collection html meta source_span typed_data universal_io]
- universal_io 2.2.2 [collection meta typed_data]
- universal_platform 1.0.0+1
- url_launcher_android 6.0.35 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_ios 6.1.4 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_linux 3.0.5 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_macos 3.0.5 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_platform_interface 2.1.2 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_web 2.0.17 [flutter flutter_web_plugins url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_windows 3.0.6 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- uuid 3.0.7 [crypto]
- vector_graphics 1.1.6 [flutter vector_graphics_codec]
- vector_graphics_codec 1.1.6
- vector_graphics_compiler 1.1.6 [args meta path_parsing xml vector_graphics_codec]
- vector_math 2.1.4
- video_player 2.6.1 [flutter html video_player_android video_player_avfoundation video_player_platform_interface video_player_web]
- video_player_android 2.4.8 [flutter video_player_platform_interface]
- video_player_avfoundation 2.4.6 [flutter video_player_platform_interface]
- video_player_platform_interface 6.1.0 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- video_player_web 2.0.16 [flutter flutter_web_plugins video_player_platform_interface]
- wakelock 0.6.2 [flutter meta wakelock_macos wakelock_platform_interface wakelock_web wakelock_windows]
- wakelock_macos 0.4.0 [flutter flutter_web_plugins wakelock_platform_interface]
- wakelock_platform_interface 0.3.0 [flutter meta]
- wakelock_web 0.4.0 [flutter flutter_web_plugins js wakelock_platform_interface]
- wakelock_windows 0.2.1 [flutter wakelock_platform_interface win32]
- webview_flutter_android 3.7.1 [flutter webview_flutter_platform_interface]
- webview_flutter_platform_interface 2.3.1 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- webview_flutter_wkwebview 3.4.4 [flutter path webview_flutter_platform_interface]
- win32 3.1.4 [ffi]
- xdg_directories 1.0.0 [meta path process]
- xml 6.3.0 [collection meta petitparser]
- yaml 3.1.2 [collection source_span string_scanner]
- youtube_explode_dart 1.12.4 [collection freezed_annotation html http http_parser json_annotation meta xml]
```

Comment: 99.9% of the time when you get that crash your document path doesn't have an even number of components - it must be `/collection/document/collection/document/...`

Comment: if this were the case then the application should not have worked for debug mode as well but it works fine while running in debug mode

Comment: All I know is that that is the most common reason for that crash. You need the error message that the firebase SDK posted when it caused the exception.  Integrate something like crashlytics or sentry crash logging.

Comment: Please provide entire stack trace of errors and explain the problem with [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so it will be easier to understand and diagnose your issue.

Comment: @RohitKharche I have added the details to the question please let me know if there is any suggestion.

Comment: How does this work? - *Close the application and remove it entirely* - and then - *Open the application again*? If it's closed and removed, how would one open it again without downloading it? Are you storing anything in User Defaults?

Comment: @jay remove from device recently opened apps not saying to uninstall it.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I have a similar issue.

Comment: check your code you may have been fetching and updating data in the same document at the same time.